# LINQ to SQL: error "Value has no literal in SQL: 00:00:00 " using nullable TimeSpan

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have defined the following Model

```
  public class TodayOrder
{
    public string ID_ORIG { get; set; }
    public string PART_ID { get; set; }
    public string PART_DEX { get; set; }
    public double TimeSecs { get; set; }
 }
```

and now I am trying to populate a List using the following Linq expression:

```
var todaysOrders = DCC.vw_ORD_GP_volumes_lastSets
 .Where(a => a.ID_ORIG == id_orig.ToUpper() && 
             a.PART_ID == Part.ToUpper())
 .Select(a => 
     new TodayOrder{ 
         ID_ORIG = a.ID_ORIG, 
         PART_ID = a.PART_ID, 
         PART_DEX = a.PART_DEX,  
         TimeSecs = a.ReqTime.GetValueOrDefault().TotalSeconds });

List<TodayOrder> lst = todaysOrders.ToList();
```

where ReqTime is of type `TimeSpan?`.

The problem is that at runtime  I am getting an error **Value has no literal in SQL: 00:00:00** - looks like there is a problem with the TimeSpan.

```
 Line 72:                     });
 Line 73:   ERROR>              lst = todaysOrders.ToList();
 Line 74:  
 [InvalidOperationException: Value has no literal in SQL: 00:00:00]
  System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.FormatValue(Object value) +584911
  System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Visitor.VisitValue(SqlValue value) +32
```

In facts, if I comment out the line setting the property TimeSecs everything is working fine.

What would be the right approach to instantiate the TodayOrder class instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Linq-to-Sql treis to translate the expression `a.ReqTime.GetValueOrDefault().TotalSeconds` to sql but it fails.

You can solve it by evaluating the query with a `ToArray()` before the select and do the select on the client side:

```
var todaysOrders = DCC.vw_ORD_GP_volumes_lastSets
 .Where(a => a.ID_ORIG == id_orig.ToUpper() && 
             a.PART_ID == Part.ToUpper())
 .ToArray()
 .Select(a => 
     new TodayOrder{ 
         ID_ORIG = a.ID_ORIG, 
         PART_ID = a.PART_ID, 
         PART_DEX = a.PART_DEX,  
         TimeSecs = a.ReqTime.GetValueOrDefault().TotalSeconds });
```

Comment: Thanks! Perfect catch. I had tried the conditional operator but it did not help, `ToArray()` instead is the right solution.